# Unit Тестирование метода ASP. NET (NUnit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit, юнит-тесты

У меня есть контроллер, который нужно протестировать. В нем есть метод, с функцией внутри.

```
public ActionResult GetZZ()
        {            
            ApplyResponseHeaders();
            var result = new MediaJsonResult();
            using (var str = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
                {
                    string inputData = str.ReadToEnd();
                    MyFunction(inputData, result);
                }
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Мне необходимо протестировать именно функцию MyFunction. Каким образом можно это сделать. Тестировать весь метод не нужно, потому что проблемы при назначении своих значений в Request.InputStream

Comment: А в чём проблема? Что вы пытались сделать? Вы создали тестовый проект? Из него вы можете запустить `MyFunction` с тестовым `inputData` и проверить результат — это не сработало?

Comment: этот метод private. Я создал экземпляр класса с этим методом..но как протестить только MyFunction  не знаю.ибо доступа к ней нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `MyFunction` — это приватная функция в классе контроллера, то у вас есть два варианта:

- Выделить ее логику в отдельную сущность, покрыть unit-тестами, а после этого заинжектить эту сущность в контроллер.

> - Если я правильно понимаю, то `MyFunction` в нынешнем варианте выполняет некоторое преобразование `(STREAM -> MEDIA_JSON_RESULT)`. На основании этого вполне себе можно вынести интерфейс с одним методом и его конкретную реализацию, после чего покрыть реализацию тестами и успокоиться.
> - Условимся, что выделенная сущность будет иметь вид `(IStreamConverter + StreamConverter)`, чтобы проще было понимать оставшуюся часть моего пассажа.
> - Этот вариант вполне себе работает в реальной жизни, но **содержит один серьезный недостаток:** даже если вы формально докажете корректность работы `StreamConverter`, ничто не мешает изменениям в методе `GetZZ` незаметно сломать видимое поведение вашего контроллера. Что самое неприятное, у вас в этом случае будет зеленый test-suite и ложная уверенность в том, что все хорошо.

- Реализовать прошлый вариант, но также дополнить его тестами на поведение самого контроллера. Такой подход не содержит недостатка, который я описал чуть выше.

> - Вам нужно будет [заmock'ать request'ы, которые поступают к контроллеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970198/how-to-mock-the-request-on-controller-in-asp-net-mvc), заmock'ать передаваемый контроллеру объект `IStreamConverter` и написать несколько тестов на его поведение в различных ситуациях. Например, если к нему поступил какой-нибудь оборвавшийся `InputStream`. Или, наоборот, вполне себе корректный `InputStream`.
> - Такие тесты нужно писать в предположении, что объект `IStreamConverter,` который инжектится в контроллер, абсолютно корректен, и всегда следует своему контракту.